# status clause in open statement showing strange behavior

Tags: fortran95

Hi here is my fortran code

```
program test

implicit none

INTEGER :: ierror
character:: filename

filename="fun"


open(unit=25,file=filename ,status="replace",action="write", &
           iostat=ierror)


              write(*,*)ierror

end program test
```

I am using Chapman's book to learn Fortran 95-2003.  According to him (page 219)`status='replace'` clause will open a new file with the name `fun` . If there is any file with such name, then it is deleted. But I created the file `fun` in the home directory where Fortran program is stored, and then ran this program. It did create a new file with name `f`. The file `fun` was not deleted. So I don't understand this behavior.... Any help appreciated......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared variable `filename` to have type `character`.  Since you've not specified a length the compiler understands it to have length 1, so your assignment

```
filename="fun"
```

leads to `filename` having the value `f`.  Change your declaration of the variable to

```
character(len=3) :: filename
```

or, probably better,

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: filename
```

The latter version uses modern (2003 and later I think) Fortran's *automatic allocation* capabilities.

Comment: I just tried your suggestions. First one is good. But the second one where your have `len=*` , gfortran throws an error. I think gfortran is not upto the 2003 standard......

Comment: @issacnewton, it's not a `gfortran` problem. `ifort` also fails to compile it and it is fully F2003 compliant. The third suggestion only works with named constants, e.g. `character(len=*), parameter :: filename = 'fun'`. The syntax for automatically allocatable strings is `character(:), allocatable :: filename`.

Comment: @HristoIliev: thanks for pointing out my sloppiness, I've edited the answer.